# Managing the selinux context of a file created on the host via a Docker container's volume

Tags: fedora, docker, selinux, fig

I ran through the [fig python / django](http://www.fig.sh/django.html) tutorial on Fedora 20 (docker 1.0.0) but it failed & tripped an AVC denial in SELinux when django-admin.py attempted to create the project files.

I reviewed the policy, i can see that setting the docker_var_lib_t context on my code dir would permit docker to write there (although i've just spied docker_share_t in the policy, that looks a better fit permissions wise - no chr / blk devices in that context).

Code directory locations are not predictable so setting a system wide policy (via semanage fcontext) doesn't seem the best way forward; i'd need to introduce some kind of convention.

Is there any way to automatically set this context on volumes mounted from a host?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the following context on the directory

chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t $HOME/code/export

then run your docker command as

docker run --rm -it -v $HOME/code/export:/exported:ro image /foo/bar